# What is the difference between state.asStateFlow() and flow.stateIn()?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

There are two equal in my opinion constructions, which of them should be used when and what are the advantages of these methods?

The first is:

```
private val _chats: MutableStateFlow<List<Chat>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
val chats: StateFlow<List<Chat>> = _chats.asStateFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.chatsFlow.collect { chats ->
            _chats.value = chats
        }
    }
}
```

The second one:

```
val chats: StateFlow<List<Chat>> = repository.chatsFlow
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000L),
        initialValue = emptyList()
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MutableStateFlow/asFlow way should be avoided. Aside from being very verbose, it continuously collects the upstream flow even when it doesn't have anything collecting from it, which wastes resources.

Comment: I should mention, this doesn't mean MutableStateFlow should be avoided altogether. I just mean it is not ideal for this pattern of directly converting a cold flow to a StateFlow. There are other use cases where MutableStateFlow is a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

Viewed on a basic level, yes. They are (nearly) the same: Both of them create `val chats`, which can then be further used in the ViewModel.

The key difference is `val _chats` - Whilst `chats` is immutable, `_chats` is mutable; and if the values of `_chats` change, the ones in `chats` will as well, allowing you to have control over the data inside of your mutable list, whilst also being able to provide an immutable list for your ViewModel.

Comment: So if my goal is just to get data from the `flow`, it makes sense to use `stateIn()`? In that case, is having a second `MutableStateFlow` field an overhead?

Comment: If you don't plan on modifying anything or changing your data set after creation I don't really see a point in doing it using `.asStateFlow`. And if you mean "overkill" by "overhead", I'd say: yes, that's overhead.

Comment: "Immutable" means guaranteed not to change in anyway whatsoever. An Int is immutable. If you have a reference to an Int, you are guaranteed its value cannot change.  A StateFlow is read-only, not immutable. If its value changes over time, it is mutating--you just aren't doing the mutation locally. Even if you do plan on changing the data, stateIn can be used after `map`, `transform` or other operators. It's always preferred because it doesn't waste resources collecting the upstream flow when there are no downstream subscribers.

Comment: Well, then I just had a huge misunderstanding of the whole (im)mutable thing... Thanks for clarifying!